# How to get and set string array in one line of code?

Tags: java, android

I have a string array `emails` and a string variable `Category_name`. To get and set the results for `Category_name` i use this:

```
holder.category_name.setText(mcategoryset.get(position).getCategory_name());
```

but for `emails` which is a string array , i am doing this:

```
holder.category_emails.setText(mcategoryset.get(position).getEmails().get(0));
```

i.e. i  am getting value of position 0 only. How can i get all the values programatically instead of getting just a single value?

Comment: For android development, you can use TextUtils lib as `holder.category_emails.setText(TextUtils.join(",",mcategoryset.get(position).getEmails()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (String email : categorySet.get(position).getEmails()) {
    if (!stringBuilder.toString().isEmpty()) {
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    stringBuilder.append(email);
}

holder.category_emails.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Sir, i am getting ',' after end of values too. What can i do to remove comma at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code

```
String emails = "";

for(int i = 0; i<mcategoryset.get(position).getEmails().size();i++){
 emails = emails+mcategoryset.get(position).getEmails().get(i)+",";
}

holder.category_emails.setText(emails);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your POJO class, for email getter add another getter, something like this,

```
public String getFullEmails(){
    StringBuilder emailString = new StringBuilder();
    int length = emails.length();
    for(for int=0; i<length; i++){
        emailString.append(emails[i]);
        if(i != length-1){
            emailString.append(",\n");
        }
    }
    return emailString.toString();
}
```

> This method of writing the logic in POJO class other than writing it in Adapter directly will provide you cleaner code and you can work on Actual adapter logic in Adapter rather than writing same Email code again and again.

Comment: Use StringBuilder instead. Remember that strings are immutable in Java. You are creating new ones at every +

Comment: @Edd, StringBuilder and String concatenations have negligible impact on performance while performing small string concatenations. Definitely StringBuilders are better for heavy task, but for getting 1 to 20 emails, String concatenation is more readable and easy to manage.

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it but for sure, for small tasks like this, it will not make a huge difference as you say. Still, it would be good to make readers aware of StringBuilder. I think your  answer would be more beneficial to general readers that way.

Comment: I recently came to know about a bug in using Concatenation in loops. So I updated my answer long back. Thanks for pointing it out. @Edd

Answer (score 0):

You can use try using java.util.Arrays which is a utility class method provided by java to ease operations like these. Try doing something like this :-

```
holder.category_emails.setText(Arrays.toString(mcategoryset.get(position).getEmails()));
```

Other options are :-

[commons-lang](https://github.com/google/guava) also have that - `ArrayUtils.toString(array)` (but prefer the JDK one)

commons-lang allows for custom separator - StringUtils.join(array, ',')

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) also allows a separator, and has the option to skip null values: `Joiner.on(',').skipNulls().join(array)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should overload your function, like `category_emails.setText(String[])` or use `for-each` to go through the value.